# How to use `with-redefs` to always throw exception from a function

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

I want to unit test exception handling parts of my code. In order to do that I am using `with-redefs` to re-bind the API's that can throw exceptions to throw an exception during the test. My test function looks something like this

```
(deftest exception-handling
  (testing "Map exception to Ring-response map"
    (with-redefs [clj-http/get
                  (constantly (throw (ex-info "unexpected error" {:cause "A terrible calamity"})))]
      (is (= 500
        (:status
          (some-function-calling-http-get arg))))
    )
  )
)
```

Running `lein test` results in an error with the message:

```
    ERROR in (exception-handling) (core.clj:4593)
Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
expected: nil
  actual: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: unexpected error
 at clojure.core$ex_info.invoke (core.clj:4593)
```

Using `(constantly (throw...` in `with-redefs` or just asserting that an exception is thrown with `thrown?` also results in the same error.

Essentially I'm looking for a macro version of `constantly`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`constantly` is a function, not a macro, so `(constantly (throw ...))` will instantly throw an error.

If you want a function that will throw an error every time it's invoked, you need something like that instead:

```
(with-redefs [clj-http/get (fn [& _] (throw (ex-info "unexpected error"
                                                     {:cause "A terrible calamity"})))]
  ...)
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. I'll edit my question to try to better reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching this in the wrong way: your tests expects the normal behavior of clj-http to return status 500 but your `with-redef` actually overwrites any clj-http code completely. In other words, your test shows that  all calls to `clj-http/get` now always (`constantly`) throws an exception. What you want instead is that `clj-http/get` always returns a 500. You could do this by using [clj-http-fake](https://github.com/myfreeweb/clj-http-fake).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [clj-http-fake](https://github.com/myfreeweb/clj-http-fake) to mock HTTP calls to external world, eg.

```
(with-fake-routes {
"http://external.api" (fn [request] {:status 500 :headers {} :body "Exception"}
  (is (= 500
       (:status
          (some-function-calling-http-get arg))))))
```